# Error trying to perform KNN in a loop with different k and subsets R studio

Tags: r

I made a loop that tests three different subsets for three different k values, but for my last value of k (k = 5) I get an error that I'm not able to understand, or know how to fix.

```
boston <- data.frame(Boston)
boston1 <- data.frame(Boston_

boston$medv01 <- ifelse((boston$medv > median(boston$medv)), 1, 0)
boston$medv <- NULL


# Subset 1:  zn - 2, chas-4, rm-6, dis-8, black-12, 
# Subset 2:  crim-1, indus-3, nox-5, age-7, tax-10, ptratio-11
# Subset 3: all
kvals <- c(1,3,5)
subset1 <- c("zn", "chas", "rm", "dis", "black")
subset2 <- c("crim", "indus", "nox", "age", "tax", "ptratio")
subset3 <- c(boston[,1:13])


x1.train <- boston[, c(subset1)]
x2.train <- boston[, c(subset2)]
x3.train <- boston[, 1:13]
y.train <- boston$medv01

xtrain.list <- list(x1.train, x2.train, x3.train)

mean(knn.cv.pred <- knn.cv(xtrain.list[[2]], y.train, k = 5) != y.train)


for (j in kvals ){
  message("~~~~ K = ", j, " ~~~~")
  for (s in seq_along(xtrain.list) ){
    knn.cv.pred <- knn.cv(xtrain.list[[s]], 
                          y.train,
                          k = kvals[j])

    message("Subset ", s, " K = ", j, " Error: ", mean(knn.cv.pred != y.train)*100, "%")
  }
  message("\n")
}

The error I get is 

~~~~ K = 1 ~~~~
Subset 1 K = 1 Error: 29.2490118577075%
Subset 2 K = 1 Error: 24.1106719367589%
Subset 3 K = 1 Error: 19.3675889328063%


~~~~ K = 3 ~~~~
Subset 1 K = 3 Error: 25.6916996047431%
Subset 2 K = 3 Error: 24.1106719367589%
Subset 3 K = 3 Error: 17.5889328063241%


~~~~ K = 5 ~~~~
Error in if (ntr - 1 < k) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Maybe replace `k = kvals[j]` with `k = j` Just a wild guess since you didn't provide a __minimal reproducible example__.

Comment: I forgot to include the library, but that actually solved the problem. Why did it occur?

Comment: Look at your for loop initialization: `for ( j in kvals ){`. Assigning k to kvals[j] doesn't make any sense.